# I'm trying to scrape from a website but its giving me an error

Tags: python, scrapy

```
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 149, in execute
    cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 251, in __init__
    super(CrawlerProcess, self).__init__(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 137, in __init__
    self.spider_loader = _get_spider_loader(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 338, in _get_spider_loader
    return loader_cls.from_settings(settings.frozencopy())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 61, in from_settings
    return cls(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 25, in __init__
    self._load_all_spiders()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 47, in _load_all_spiders
    for module in walk_modules(name):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 71, in walk_modules
    submod = import_module(fullpath)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/sid/scrapytutorial/quotetutorial/quotetutorial/spiders/quotes_spider.py", line 28, in <module>
    cd
NameError: name 'cd' is not defined
```

I'm not able to figure out why I'm getting this error. Is this related to file structure or is this some kind of internal error. Do I have to make a different folder and try again?

Here's what I have done so far:

quotes_spider.py file

```
import scrapy
from ..items import QuotetutorialItem

class QuoteScrapy(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        items = QuotetutorialItem()

        all_div_quotes = response.css('div.quote')

        for quotes in all_div_quotes:
            title = quotes.css('span.text::text').extract()
            author = quotes.css('.author::text').extract()
            tag = quotes.css('.tag::text').extract()

            items['title'] = title
            items['author'] = author
            items['tag'] = tag

        yield items
```

items.py

```
import scrapy

class QuotetutorialItem(scrapy.Item):

    title = scrapy.Field()
    author = scrapy.Field()
    tag = scrapy.Field()
```

please look into this and tell me what is it I'm doing wrong

Comment: I think we'll need to see the source for `/Users/sid/scrapytutorial/quotetutorial/quotetutorial/spiders/quotes_spider.py`.

Comment: did the changes, take a look.

Comment: Scrapy is loading the `/Users/sid/scrapytutorial/quotetutorial/quotetutorial/spiders/quotes_spider.py` file, and that looks like where the problem is. Can you show us that file?

Comment: First one is quotes_spider.py file

Comment: The traceback indicates that the issue is on line 28 of `quotes_spider.py`, but you've given us only 25 lines of it. Perhaps you've accidentally typed some more into that file? Maybe a `cd` which was supposed to go into a terminal rather than the python code?

Comment: Yeah, I've made that correction but still giving me this error. This is after I made that correction.

Comment: Nevertheless, the problem is with line 28 of `quotes_spider.py`, which we can't see.

Comment: Unless you are now getting a different traceback?

Comment: There is nothing on line 28. I've checked and then save the file.

Comment: `from ..items` -> items.py really is in the folder above?

Comment: If line 28 of `/Users/sid/scrapytutorial/quotetutorial/quotetutorial/spiders/quotes_spider.py` is genuinely empty, then you must be getting a different traceback now.

Comment: I'm sorry but still getting the same error. I think I have to make a new directory and check again.